# PUT request in Restify API, NodeJS, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, put, restify

I am trying to write a PUT request for my API. I'm using restify to build the API.
I keep getting the errors, could you please help?

```
    //PUT (Update) Items

    app.put('/items/:item_id', function(req, res){

    var query = Item.where({_id: req.params.item_id});
    query.findById(req.params.id, function (err, items) {
    item.name = req.body.name;
    item.description = req.body.description;
    item.url = req.body.url;

    req.item.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("updated");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.send(204, item);
    });
});
```

I tried testing it using POSTMAN client and I get this error

```
     {
         "code": "InternalError",
         "message": "Object #<Query> has no method 'findById'"
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: @mfitzp  I tried testing it using POSTMAN client and I get this error                 {
    "code": "InternalError",
    "message": "Object #<Query> has no method 'findById'"
}

Comment: `findById` is a mongoose convenience method. If you are using the native `mongodb` driver then you will have to use `find({_id:req.params.id})`

Answer (score 0):

The findById method internally maps to find with the parameter {_id: }

You can use either:

```
Item.find({_id: req.params.item_id}, function (err, items) {

});
```

or

```
Item.findById(req.params.item_id, function (err, items) {

});
```

Both are the same thing. The reason is because when you write

```
 var query = Item.where({_id: req.params.item_id});
```

A query object is returned, on which the findById method cannot be called. It can only be called on the Item model.

If you are trying to combine queries, I would suggest combining them at the filter level or use aggregation.

Comment: thank you, I changed it to query.find and i got the error 'item' is not defined

Comment: Please see the change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i changed it and i am getting the error on POSTMAN
'"code": "InternalError",
    "message": "item is not defined"'

Comment: Have you created the Item model using mongoose? If yes, have you imported to the file using require?